# creating an array to create a json format

Tags: javascript, php, html, arrays, json

I have multiselect field .I want to get the value from the field and push the value as I have four multiselect and get the value in in jquery.I want to create an array and push hthe field values accordingly.I'm struck with creating an array and push the value.

```js
$(".go").click(function(){

   var filter =[];
  var username=$( "#username" ).val();
  var geo=$( "#geo" ).val();
  var week=$( "#week" ).val();
  var team=$( "#team" ).val();
  filter[username]=username;
  filter[geo]=geo;
  filter[week]=week;
  filter[team]=team;
  
  console.log(filter[username]);
  var userarr=JSON.stringify(filter);
  console.log(userarr);
 });
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-popup" id="filter" style="display: block;">
 <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
 <select id="username" multiple=""><option selected="true" disabled="">Username</option><option>user1</option><option>user2</option><option>user3</option><option>user4</option></select>
 <select id="geo" multiple=""><option selected="true" disabled="">Geo</option><option>chennai</option><option>covai</option><option>hydrabad</option><option>cochin</option><option>mumbai</option></select>
 <select id="week" multiple=""><option selected="true" disabled="">Weeks</option><option>week1</option><option>week2</option><option>week3</option><option>week4</option></select>
 <select id="team" multiple=""><option selected="true" disabled="">Teams</option><option>Java</option><option>Lamp</option><option>Oracle</option><option>Sales</option></select>
 <button class="go">GO</button>
 </div>
```

required json format

```
{"username":{"user1","user2","user3"},
  "geo":{"geo1","geo2"},
  "week":{"week2","week4"} 
}
```

Comment: `{"user1","user2","user3"}` this is not valid array syntax. You either want `["user1","user2","user3"]` to make it a valid array or add keys/values to make it a valid object.

Comment: thats a json format

Comment: [Not valid JSON](https://www.json.org/)

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="form-popup" id="filter" style="display: block;">
    <form id="test">
         <select id="username" name="username" multiple=""><option selected="true" disabled="">Username</option><option>user1</option><option>user2</option><option>user3</option><option>user4</option></select>
         <select id="geo" name="geo" multiple=""><option selected="true" disabled="">Geo</option><option>chennai</option><option>covai</option><option>hydrabad</option><option>cochin</option><option>mumbai</option></select>
         <select id="week" name="week" multiple=""><option selected="true" disabled="">Weeks</option><option>week1</option><option>week2</option><option>week3</option><option>week4</option></select>
         <select id="team" name="team" multiple=""><option selected="true" disabled="">Teams</option><option>Java</option><option>Lamp</option><option>Oracle</option><option>Sales</option></select>
         <button type="button" class="go">GO</button>
    </form>
 </div>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    $(".go").click(function(){
        var value={};
        $.each($('#test').serializeArray(),function(k,v){
            if(!(value[v.name]))
                value[v.name]={};
           value[v.name][k]=v.value;
        });
        console.log(value);
    });
 </script>
```